# How to rearrange magento 2 page block div by XML code or something else?

Tags: magento2

I want to rearrange my magento2 page HTML blocks I tried by XML tags but its moving but I can't move what I have to place the exact place so please help me to customize the page block or anyone have a page customization tool or any other tips?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on what you are trying to achieve? Best would be code of what you tried to do.

Comment: http://magento2.templatemela.com/MAG2012/MAG110246_1/checkout/#shipping

I want to move apply discount option to top of proceed to checkout div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Theme you need to place a `checkout_cart_index.xml` under `Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/`

There you can use the move directive like this

```
<move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.summary" before="checkout.cart.summary.title"></move>
```